# Why filtered views get blown away when edit view is selected?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, sharepoint-list-filter

I am using Modern SharePoint List experience. I am doing following thing.

1. Filtering Items using Modern SharePoint Filter Options.
2. Saving the filtered result as view and it worked.

But now when I edit the current view, all the filter get reset again even I hit the cancel button and I have to apply all those filter again.

Is this a normal behavior of SharePoint Online Modern Experience?

Any suggestion and documentation link will be most welcomed.

Comment: How are you filtering the list items? From list view settings or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue.
Here are my steps:

1. In the Filters pane, select relevant column value, and save view with a new view name.
   [image]
2. Then edit current view:

[image]

3. The Filter section display as below, when I cancel to edit the view, the custom view work as well.
   [image]

You can check if the list view is your newly created view after cancel to edit the list view.

Or create a new list and check if the issue exists.